# Does New-PSDrive behaves different when mapping to Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, powershell-3.0

I try to map a shared folder that is shared on a box running under **Windows Server 2008 R2** by using as the script snippet below:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -string "myPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("fooUser", $password)

New-PSDrive -name "temproraryPSDrive" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\ABC.otherDomain.FooBar.com"-Credential $credentials -Scope Script -ErrorAction Stop
```

And when I check the **Event Viewer**, of the box that has the shared folder I map to, I see New-PSDrive :

- **First** attempted to logon **by using the default user**, and then **Logon Faiulure** occurred due to lack of permissions.
- And then ONLY **AFTER then**, New-PSDrive uses the credentials I have provided which helps to Logon sucesfully.

However, when I try to map a shared folder that is on a box with **Windows Server 2003 R2**, PS

- Always attempts to logon by using the credentials in the first place.

**QUESTION**:
Do you know WHY, New-PSDrive attempts to logon by using the default user even tough I provide credentials when it attempts to map something on **Windows Server 2008 R2** whereas it uses the credentials in the first place when I map something on **Windows Server 2003 R2** ?